# Golang: for loop with range condition to restart

Tags: go

I'm trying to make this loop restart every time a name is already in the list, this code is obviously only going to check this once. Is there any way to make the loop restart from beginning? Thanks!

```
for _, client := range list.clients {
//for i := 0; i < len(list.clients); i++ {
    if(client.name==name){
        connection.Write([]byte("Name already exists please try another one:\n"))
        bytesRead, _ := connection.Read(reply)
            name = string(reply[0:bytesRead])
        name = strings.TrimSuffix(name, "\n")

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Wrap it in another `for`:

```
Loop:
    for {
        for _, client := range list.clients {
            if client.name == name {
                connection.Write([]byte("Name already exists please try another one:\n"))
                bytesRead, _ := connection.Read(reply)
                name = string(reply[0:bytesRead])
                name = strings.TrimSuffix(name, "\n")
                continue Loop // Start over
            }
        }
        break // Got through it; we're done
    }
```

You can also just reset your index. `range` may be the wrong tool here:

```
for i := 0; i < len(list.clients); i++ {
    client := list.clients[i]
    if client.name == name {
        connection.Write([]byte("Name already exists please try another one:\n"))
        bytesRead, _ := connection.Read(reply)
        name = string(reply[0:bytesRead])
        name = strings.TrimSuffix(name, "\n")
        i = -1 // Start again
    }
}
```

Comment: wow! works great! I'm going to try the other option also. There is no way to reset range? Because this is more academic exercise! Thank you some much it works great! Where i can find more documentation about Loop? thanks again!

Comment: "Loop" here is just a label. It could be anything. The key is `continue`. See the section "Switch" in Effective Go (http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html). Also the `continue` documentation in the Go spec (http://golang.org/ref/spec#Continue_statements). No, `range` can't be reset. You can `range` over a channel, and it's not possible to reset that.

Comment: "range can't be reset. You can range over a channel, and it's not possible to reset that." Great that makes sense and now I understand why! thank you some much for your time!